# Using filters for carraydataprovider yii

Tags: yii

I am using CArrayDataProvider for CGridView in Yii, I am not able to use filters.

Can anyone tell me how to use filters. I don't have specific model, i'm fetching data from different tables.

Answer (score 0):

`CArrayDataProvider` doesn't have filter property (as `CActiveDataProvider`) and you'll need to implement this feature yourself. Event if you are fetching data from different tables you can still use `ActiveRecord` with `CActiveDataProvider` and [filters by related models](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/281/searching-and-sorting-by-related-model-in-cgridview/)

Comment: I want input tag for each column above, so that i can type and search. Thank You for your reply above.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this page for a good working example (Comment 5501): http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/232/using-filters-with-cgridview-and-carraydataprovider/#c5501
I'm using this in one of my applications